# Rails console query returns different results compared to pure sql query

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

So in my Rails console I have an active record query that generates an SQL. I look in my `logs/development` and I can see the SQL that is being generated.

For some reason I'm not getting the expected results when I run the active record query. I looked into my logs and copied/pasted the sql into the console that is connected to my database and then suddenly that returns the correct results. Any ideas why this is happening? I'm using PostgreSQL.

I'm trying to find stores that were opened in the past 5 hours.

EDIT subtracting 10 hours makes this query work....

ActiveRecord call (within is from geokit gem):

```
Store.within(10, :origin =>[30.267153000000000, -97.743060799999970]).where("date > current_timestamp - interval '5 hours'")
```

SQL generated:

```
SELECT "store".*, 
 (ACOS(least(1,COS(0.5282614750548792)*COS(-1.705938231937002)*COS(RADIANS(store.lat))*COS(RADIANS(store.lng))+
 COS(0.5282614750548792)*SIN(-1.705938231937002)*COS(RADIANS(store.lat))*SIN(RADIANS(store.lng))+
 SIN(0.5282614750548792)*SIN(RADIANS(store.lat))))*3963.19)
 AS distance FROM "store" WHERE ((store.lat>30.122583147146404 AND store.lat<30.41172285285359 AND store.lng>-97.91044799232348 AND store.lng<-97.57567360767642)) AND ((
 (ACOS(least(1,COS(0.5282614750548792)*COS(-1.705938231937002)*COS(RADIANS(store.lat))*COS(RADIANS(store.lng))+
 COS(0.5282614750548792)*SIN(-1.705938231937002)*COS(RADIANS(store.lat))*SIN(RADIANS(store.lng))+
 SIN(0.5282614750548792)*SIN(RADIANS(store.lat))))*3963.19)
 <= 10)) AND (date > current_timestamp - interval '5 hours')
```

Comment: Is it possible that the stores weren't open when you ran the query the first time, but that they *were* open when you ran it at the console? In other words, is this repeatble? Do you still get different results from the same query?

Comment: nah that's not possible. they are non changing dates. I can repeat a query and get the same results. nothing changes.

Comment: I do have to say that if I subtract enough hours then I get the results expected. say I subtract "date > current_timestamp - interval '10 hours'"  ... then it works

Comment: It seems to me that ActiveRecord generates the correct query, so i am puzzled why it should not return the same objects. Is the `date` a `DateTime` field? Do you have an `after_find` or `after_initialize` method?

Comment: yea date is a datetime. I'm gonna have to dig around the geokit gems to see if there is a after_find/after_initialize method call

Answer (score 0):

```
. . . .where("date > current_timestamp - interval '5 hours'")
```

Standard SQL syntax for this WHERE clause should be

```
WHERE "date" > current_timestamp - interval '5' hour
```

In standard SQL, *date* is a reserved word; reserved words used as column names need to be in double quotes. Note that the number is within single quotes, and that the keywords *interval* and *hour* aren't quoted. Support for standard SQL varies wildly, especially in your neighborhood. (Quoting of reserved words and date arithmetic.)

So . . . check the docs for your target platform to make sure you're quoting (or not quoting) these two things correctly.

I'm having a hard time convincing myself that this could the the cause of your problem, though.